# curve_fit to vary only the last three parametres while two values are known

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to fit 3 model parameters to curve_fit with 2 known parameters. Here's an example (that doesn't work but I think this is pretty much what I should be doing)

```
def richards(t, beta, l_f, nu, k, t_m):
    denom = 1 + nu * np.exp(-k * (t - t_m))
    return beta + l_f / np.power(denom, 1/nu)

for i, (r, c) in enumerate(coords):
    params[i, :] = curve_fit(
        f     = richards,
        xdata = ts,
        ydata = plates[0, r, c]
    )[0]
```

So the question is how do I incorporate the known variables so that only 3 variables need to be fitted?

Comment: Could you specify the fixed parameters and the ones that should be fitted?

Answer (score 0):

Say you know that `beta = 2` and `nu = 3`. Then you can define an auxiliary function

```py
def f(t, l_f, k, t_m): 
    return richards(t=t, beta=2, l_f=l_f, nu=3, k=k, t_m=t_m)
```

and pass this function to the modelling function:

```py
... curve_fit(f=f, ...)
```